# How to highlight the specific lines of code snippet present in markdown using jekyll?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

We are converting the md (markdown) files in to html files using Jekyll and hosting the html files in site.

I would like to highlight the specific line of the code snippet like below.

[Microsoft Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ra7z.png)

I have checked Microsoft source by inspecting. They done like this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#customize-courses-pages

[Microsoft Document Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WepMs.png)

My MD file code snippet section will be like below.

{% highlight c# %}

```
int x = 5;
int y = 6;
int sum = x + y;
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

{% endhighlight %}

For example , I have to highlight the line no 3 (int sum = x + y;) with yellow.

How to achieve this ?